# Can ArcGIS Desktop read any open source layer definitions?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, symbology, layer-file

I am looking for a non-proprietary way to store layer symbology for both vector and raster layers and then load those layers in ArcGIS Desktop 10.x.

I have used layer files for this purpose for many years. At runtime I load the layer file, retrieve the renderer and apply it to the layer I am loading into the current map document. Something like this:

```
IGxLayer pGXLayer = new GxLayer();
IGxFile pGXFile = (IGxFile)pGXLayer;
pGXFile.Path = symbology.FullName;
```

However layer files are proprietary and annoyingly version specific.

Is anyone aware of an open source symbology definition that ArcGIS Desktop can use? Something like [QML](https://opengislab.com/blog/tag/QGIS+QML)? Is it true that ArcGIS Desktop cannot use QML files?

Comment: You should read about the "SLYR ESRI to QGIS Compatibility suite" of North Road
https://north-road.com/slyr/ Updates of November 2019:
https://north-road.com/2019/11/06/slyr-esri-to-qgis-compatibility-suite-november-2019-update/ Updates of April 2020:
https://north-road.com/2020/04/28/slyr-esri-to-qgis-compatibility-suite-april-2020-update/
Of course, this answer is not very suitable, but nonetheless it may help you.